# loop through api data array to get values from objects

Tags: javascript

I have data like so:

```
var data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}]
```

I want to loop through this data, and get the values of the keys. The result I am looking for is 123.

I have tried:

```
var result = [];
for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    result.push(data[i]);
}
```

However, all it is doing is pushing the objects into the variable array 'result'.

So the question is, how do i get the value of data IE 1, 2, and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do.

```
var data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}]
var result = [];

// read all items of data.
data.forEach(function(item) {

     // read all keys of item.
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
        result.push(item[key]);
    });

});
```

Or ES6

```
  const data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}]
  let result = [];

  data.forEach(item => {
     result = [...result, ...Object.values(item)];
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add that in some browsers (and nodejs 7) you could use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) like this

```js
var data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}];

var values = data.map(o=>Object.values(o)[0]);

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your data structure doesn't change, meaning, **you have exactly one key-value pair in each object entry**, use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the entries and then call [**`Object.keys`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with the current `object` and use `[0]` to get the actual key *(e.g. `one`, `two`, `three`)* and return the value of the `object` using the key, then you can manipulate the way you need the `result`:

#### ES6 Example:

```js
const data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}];
const result = data.map(object => object[Object.keys(object)[0]]);

console.log(result);
console.log(result.join(','));
console.log(result.join(''));
```

#### ES5 Example:

```js
var data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}];
var result = data.map(function (object) { 
  return object[Object.keys(object)[0]] 
});

console.log(result);
console.log(result.join(','));
console.log(result.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the values from the objects like so:

```
var result = [];
data.foreach((item) => {
    item.keys().foreach( (key) => {
        result.push(item[key]);
    });
});
```

When you have the data already inside the array you can simply do

```
var dataString = result.join('');
```

This function takes all the values in the array and concatenates into a string, with the given string as a separator. Passing in a blank string makes it not use a separator.

Alternatively you can do:

```
var result = "";
data.foreach((item) => {
    item.keys().foreach( (key) => {
        result += item[key];
    });
});
```

As this will concatenate the string directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `reduce`, `Object.values` and a `spread`?

```
const data = [{one:1}, {two:2}, {three:3}]

const flatMapValues = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((collection, item)=> collection = [...collection, ...Object.values(item)], [])
}
```

This would scale better as it would convert all of your values into one array.

```
const data = [{one:1, four: 4}, {two:2, five:5}, {three:3, six: 6}]

const flatMapValues = arr => {
  return arr
    .reduce((collection, item)=> collection = [...collection, ...Object.values(item)], [])
    .sort((a, b) => a > b)
}
```